# software setup for php web application with mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, lamp, setup-project

I have been developing an application in php with mysql database. I would like to know whether it is possible to create a setup to install the php application in LAMP? 
Also i would like to know whether it is possible to create a setup to install LAMP and my application through a single setup?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Hi, I need to create a software setup which will install both LAMP and my php application. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think [Bitnami lamp stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp) is what you are looking for